# Does Postgres protect the hard drive from repeated writes to the same memory cells?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space

If I have the same row in the same column in the same table to which I write 4 bytes (an integer) 100,000 times a day, will that wear out the SSD? For an SSD 400 kb per day is nothing, yet writing it to the same memory cell would pop it.

- Does the Postgres database management system juggle these cells
  somehow under the hood?
- Or do modern SSD chips do it in the
  hardware?
- Or does it all get written to the same memory cell and we
  just swap dead SSDs as time goes by?

Comment: Postgres doesn't actually overwrite the row, but creates a new one, maybe even on a different (filesystem) block. I doubt that Postgres has any influence on where the disk actually puts this

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so that would necessarily write it to a separate cell. An SSD controller chip sequences new writes to go into the least used cells by default. This would be the most fail-safe way to do it indeed. Where could I find documentation confirming that Postgres does actually makes new writes every single time? Or perhaps there are exceptions? Wouldn't want to walk into an exception without knowing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Introduction:

What **must** be appreciated is that PostgreSQL knows **nothing** about the underlying disks (whether they're spinning rust or SSDs, RAID-configured or **anything** else). PostgreSQL hands the data over to the OS and trusts the OS to look after it ([sometimes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fsync_Errors) not a good idea)!

For SSDs, there are two factors to be considered here:

> - Wear-levelling
> - TRIM-ming

It is **important** to note that **neither** of these has anything to do with applications (i.e. PostgreSQL, any other database server or any app) which run on the system! The former is strictly a property/capability of the SSD itself, the latter a "cooperation method" between the OS and the SSD.

### Wear-levelling:

Take-home message: The SSD distributes writes to different blocks **evenly** because SSD blocks can only undergo a `limited number of erase cycles before becoming unreliable`!

From the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling):

> Wear leveling attempts to work around these limitations by arranging
> data so that erasures and re-writes are distributed evenly across the
> medium. In this way, no single erase block prematurely fails due to a
> high concentration of write cycles.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_uring) In flash memory, a single block
> on the chip is designed for longer life than the others so that the
> memory controller can store operational data with less chance of its
> corruption.[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing))

So, the SSD decides where to actually put the data that's coming from the OS (note: no mention of which application(s) this data may be coming from). The simple idea is that it spreads these writes around the drive to equalise the wear on all of the disk's blocks so that some blocks won't prematurely fail!

This can become complicated very quickly - see the wiki for more details:

[image]

### TRIM-ming:

Take-home message: Because of the underlying structure of SSDs, only empty blocks can be written to - if there is already data in a block, this old data must be read and rewritten back to the block along with the new data - this contributes to [write-amplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification).

If the OS tells the disk (post-delete) that the data in block x is no longer required, the disk can perform garbage-collection (can be scheduled) and the block will be empty and then ready for writing with no write-amplification. Not altogether dissimilar from defragmenting an HDD.

(again from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) - apologies for the long quote, but it's necessary):

> SSDs store data in flash memory cells that are grouped into pages
> typically of 4 to 16 kiB, grouped together into blocks of typically
> 128 to 512 pages. Example: 512 kiB blocks that group 128 pages of 4
> kiB each.[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) NAND flash memory cells can be directly written to
> only when they are empty. If they happen to contain data, the contents
> must be erased before a write operation. An SSD write operation can be
> done to a single page but, due to hardware limitations, erase commands
> always affect entire blocks;[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) consequently, writing data to empty
> pages on an SSD is very fast, but slows down considerably once
> previously written pages need to be overwritten. Since an erase of the
> cells in the page is needed before it can be written to again, but
> only entire blocks can be erased, an overwrite will initiate a
> read-erase-modify-write cycle:[7][12] the contents of the entire block
> are stored in cache, then the entire block is erased from the SSD,
> then the overwritten page(s) is written into the cached block, and
> only then can the entire updated block be written to the flash medium.
> This phenomenon is known as write amplification.[13][14]
>
> Operation The TRIM command enables an operating system to notify the
> SSD of pages which no longer contain valid data. For a file deletion
> operation, the operating system will mark the file's sectors as free
> for new data, then send a TRIM command to the SSD. After trimming, the
> SSD will not preserve any contents of the block when writing new data
> to a page of flash memory, resulting in less write amplification
> (fewer writes), higher write throughput (no need for a
> read-erase-modify sequence), thus increasing drive life.

### The future of storage:

There is much interesting research ongoing re. storage and, for obvious reasons, storage in databases. While this is becoming above my pay-grade in terms of expertise, if you search for terms such as "byte-addressable disk", you will come across sites such as [here](https://pmem.io/) which is home to a Persistent Memory (Byte-addressable) toolkit (Intel [Optane](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/optane-dc-persistent-memory.html) can support his apparently), so the days of reading and writing data by the block may be numbered?

For an explanation of why we have blocks in the first place, see [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/378084/why-do-disks-write-data-in-chunks-of-page-size) on software-engineering and see here for an interesting discussion about user-mode direct access to hardware, "bypassing" the OS... all fascinating stuff! [io_uring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_uring) (and eBPF) appear to be the [new kids](https://www.scylladb.com/2020/05/05/how-io_uring-and-ebpf-will-revolutionize-programming-in-linux/) on the Linux block, but you can peruse that at your leisure.

### Answering the questions:

> If I have the same row in the same column in the same table to which I
> write 4 bytes (an integer) 100,000 times a day, will that wear out the
> SSD? For an SSD 400 kb per day is nothing, yet writing it to the same
> memory cell would pop it.

My take on the above is that the SSD would spread the writes out over many blocks - leading to a lot of work. How **exactly** this would be done would depend on the SSD's wear-levelling algorithms.

> Does the Postgres database management system juggle these cells somehow under the hood?

Absolutely **not**! PostgreSQL just hands data off to the file system and lets the FS & OS take care of the storage (although see [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fsync_Errors) for where that process broke down due to a flaw in Linux). This is as it should be - [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

> Or do modern SSD chips do it in the hardware?

My readings in this area lead me to believe that it's the SSD firmware that looks after wear-levelling and TRIM-ming.

> Or does it all get written to the same memory cell and we just swap dead SSDs as time goes by?

There is normally a small high wear-tolerant area on the SSD where the block write data is kept and some of them can have reserve areas for when blocks start to fail - obviously, the more sophisticated your SSD, the more you'll pay for it.

To reiterate: PostgreSQL has no **knowledge off** or **control over** what happens the data once it hands it off to the OS - is it buffered, straight to disk, lost with all hands?

This will depend on the OS's own scheduling algorithms and the load that it's under - another whole area of computer science! :-) p.s. +1 for an interesting question that made me learn about this (was on to-do list!).

Answer (score 2):

Postgres doesn't write the data file for each change.  Like most RDBMSs it uses [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/wal-intro.html), and only occasionally updates the data files.

> Using WAL results in a significantly reduced number of disk writes,
> because only the log file needs to be flushed to disk to guarantee
> that a transaction is committed, rather than every data file changed
> by the transaction.

So even without SSD wear leveling, you won't see a large number of writes to the same location in a file because the logs are written sequentially, and the data files only updated during a scheduled [CHECKPOINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-checkpoint.html), or other background process.